# Nested foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC Core NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a navigation sidebar in a simple web app that has two primary models, and I'm running into a peculiar error when I try to use a nested loop to render data in the sidebar.

My app has two models like Category and Thing in the example below:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

public class Thing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a sidebar that contains a list of all my Categories. I created a ViewComponent that I'm referencing in _Layout.cshtml like so:

```
// SidebarViewComponent.cs
public class SidebarViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MyContext db;

    public SidebarViewComponent(MyContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var categories = await GetCategoriesAsync();
        return View(categories);
    }

    private Task<List<Category>> GetCategoriesAsync()
    {
        return db.Category.ToListAsync();
    }
}

// View file for SidebarViewComponent
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Category>
<div id="sidebar">
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <div class="header">@category.Name</div>
            @foreach (var thing in @category.Things)
            {
                <div>@thing.Title</div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

// _Layout.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Sidebar")
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

When I access a page that's rendered by my ThingController, this works perfectly. But on my home page or any page handled by CategoryController, I get the error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line `@foreach (var thing in @category.Things)`.

How can I get this sidebar to work on every page?

Comment: I can't found any code for `ThingController` & `CategoryController`, can you provide it? Also are you sure if `public virtual ICollection<Things> Thing { get; set; }` is right property declaration over `public virtual ICollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }`? I suspected `CategoryController` doesn't provide `Things` collection when passing to view, so foreach loop throwing NRE.

Comment: I fixed the declaration of the `Things` collection in my question. It was already right in my real code, but I typed it wrong here in my MWE. My Controller classes are the boilerplate that Visual Studio 2017 creates when you add a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to get this working by changing my ViewComponent's `GetCategoriesAsync` method to use eager loading of the related collection:

```
private Task<List<Category>> GetCategoriesAsync()
{
    return db.Category.Include(c => c.Things).ToListAsync();
}
```

[This Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) pointed me in the right direction.